# How to filter/drag impurity particles in a pure liquid

Tags: electrostatics, fluid-statics

I wonder about following scenario: Given a pure liquid, let's assume oil but an ageing case. The case causes that impurities (water, gases,..) enter over time resulting in a more and more impure oil.
The goal is to collect all these impurities.
Let's call the case actually a tank which is, e.g., of 5x5x5m³.

I'm not that into materials but maybe someone knows something how to catch everything except one substance.
What I even wonder more is: Would it be possible to use an electrode so all these impurities will be kind of dragged to that electrode?
I also thought about heating everything up so buoyancy will automatically localize these particles. But I think the heat gradient will cause a chaotic stream of particles inside.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot have a single electrode, all electrodes come in pairs: anode ($+$ charged) and cathode ($-$ charged).

The only substances that can be 'caught' on these electrodes are ionic compounds, i.e. substances that on solvation split into positively charged ions (or cations) and negatively charged ions (or anions), for illustration ($s$ stands for 'solvated'):

$$AB_{(s)}\to A^+_{(s)} + B^-_{(s)}$$

The resp. cations and anions will then find their way to the opposite charged electrodes (if present)

Generally speaking, oil, whether organic or hydrocarbon in nature, is a very poor dielectric medium, which does not split ionic compounds very well.

And most gases or water do not form ionic compounds in such medium anyway.

So your proposed method of purification is unlikely to succeed.

Comment: A single electrode would imply the case is on ground(?).
Do I need ions? E.g. water can form a dipole.. but it will probably be too weak. Aren't there any industrial cases where liquids have to be filtered? Only mechanical filter and bacteria come into my mind. Is there something more fancy? :)

Comment: You can't catch stuff on an electrode, unless that stuff is charged, so yes, you NEED ions. Water has a dipole but not a net, permanent charge: it's not a ion. Water does "auto-dissociate" but only for a vanishingly small proportion. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: Look up *molecular filters*.

Comment: I hoped there would be something magic that uses van-der-waals-forces :) Thanks for the hint!

Comment: VDW forces really only explain internal cohesion in a fluid or gas.